# why len(x) is zero when x=b''?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. Can anybody please explain how len() works in python3 for the below mentioned example?

```
x = b''
print(len(x))
```

The output comes out to be `0`.

A `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` is displayed if any value other than `b''` is used. (eg: `a''`, `c''`, `bb''`, `b!`)

Comment: `b''` is an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

the `b` prefix indicate that that string is a [byte string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects). Therefore, the x is actually a sequence of bytes with a length of 0.

```
>>> len('')
0    
>>> len(b'')
0
```

Edit: as [@Marco Bonelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889449/marco-bonelli) has pointed out, `b''` is a `bytes` object, which is not same as `''` (a `str` object)

```
>>> ('' == '')
True
>>> (b'' == '')
False
```

Comment: Nice improvement! Here's the [official doc link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the other answer from yesterday is correct. `b''` is a bytes object, but bb'' or c'' or a'' is not any type of
obj. :))).

But you can use some letter about that (example r(raw
string)).
Ex:

```
example_var = r"hi \n hello"
print(example_var)
#Do you think it's print hi
#hello? It's incorrect :>. I tried to do that in my IDE before. It's print hi \n hello
```

Thanks for very much reading.